# How do I deploy app on Microsoft Surface tablet using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-rt

The Microsoft surface uses the ARM7 which is the same as the Windows Phone. I thought that using the Windows Phone 8 SDK and Visual Studio 2012 I could deploy the app to tablet. When I developed apps for the Windows Phone it was straight forward to register the phone in the Dev Center, and pushing the app was easy by using Visual Studio or Application Deployment Tool.

I did iOS development with Xcode and I can set the target device to iPad or iPhone. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't use the Windows Phone 8 SDK to develop for Surface.

Comment: Develop your app on Windows 8 desktop first, it is a wholeheckofalot easier.  Checking that it still works on RT is something you do last.

Answer (score 18):

There is a couple of steps that need to be done for this. Visual Studio allows you to remotely push your app to a device (provided that both the PC and Surface are connected to the same network).

Basically you go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#remote-tools) and download the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 (near the bottom of the page) onto your Surface (remembering to download the ARM version).

You can then launch this program on your Surface.

Then in Visual Studio you can click the little drop down arrow next to the run button and choose "Remote Device". If both your development machin and your Surface are on the same network it should detect it automatically (but you may have to enter your Surface's IP address).

The first time the app is deployed onto the device the Surface will prompt you to get a developer certificate and once that has occurred it should just work.

[This guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/06/12/what-you-need-to-know-about-developing-for-windows-on-arm-woa.aspx) explains it far better then me and should give you all the information you need.

Goodluck!

Comment: OK, I also see it will be useful to use Portal Portable Class Library prohttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110)

Comment: You said to use a windows 8 desktop for the start of the project. Does it make sense to use the windows store or windows metro app templates in visual studio?